# Blank dock, command+tab menu icon for application - RubyMine 7.0

Tags: macos, dock, permission, icon

I'm having a problem with the application icon for Jetbrains' RubyMine 7.0 not showing up in the dock.

[image: blank dock icon]

This used to work just fine before I cloned/renamed the user accounts on my Mac, running Yosemite.

One of my user accounts is able to see the icon in the dock, the other is not.  I believe the problem is with the account that was cloned from the original account.

Things I've tried:

- Fixing permissions through diskutility
- Uninstalling application, deleting all ~/Library files for the app and reinstalling.
- `chown -R  ~/ (to ensure proper file ownership after account clone/rename)

Help is appreciated.

EDIT: Just to add a few other things:

- Sometimes, for seemingly no reason, the application icon will reappear in the dock.  As strange as it sounds, there is no obvious action that causes it to come back.  It will certainly disappear shortly after.
- The icon is also missing from application dialogs and from the command+tab switching menu.

[image: missing from dialog]

Comment: Can you see the app's icon in /Applications? Is it just when the app is on the dock that the icon is gone?

Comment: Yep. It's there in /Applications. On the dock it's missing. It's also missing from the command+tab menu for switching between apps.

Comment: I did end up resolving the issue, though I'm not sure exactly what I changed.  I was altering some file permissions (somewhere in /Library I think) while troubleshooting my homebrew setup, and this issue got resolved as well.

Answer (score 1):

I recover from all sort of temporary dock corruption by killing the dock after saving work and getting ready to restart the Mac.

- `killall Dock` from terminal app
- log out and back in
- restart the Mac

Barring that, you've got more serious corruption, but let's start with the quick triage first.

The next steps would be to make a new user account and repeat installing your app on that user’s desktop and drag it into the dock.

Comment: Nope.  Unfortunately @bmike, that didn't work.

Comment: @JonWorek I’ve added next steps for you.